# Pointer not modifying the address?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, crash

I was writing a C++ program to test my pointer and reference knowledge and so grabbed an address and I couldn't modify the value in it which was 0;
Any idea why that happened? I named the line "buggy line"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value = 6;
    int* point = &value;
    int value2 = 9000;
    *point = 5;
    point = &value2;
    point+=4000;
    *point = 0;  //the buggy line
    cout << *point << endl;
    cout << value;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `point+=4000` to do?

Comment: The behaviour of `point+=4000;` is undefined. What output did you expect?

Comment: You are incrementing the pointer from 4000. That means your pointer holds an address 4000*sizeof(int) farther in memory.

Comment: @molbdnilo No it is not, why would pointer arithmetic be undefined?

Comment: @CoryKramer "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined." (§5.7)

Comment: Actually I got an initial address and then wanted to move to another one 4000 bytes away from it and modify that one. I could go without modifying it and it printed out a 0. When I tried to modify it I couldnt. The program would crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
point+=4000;
*point = 0;  //the buggy line
```

These two lines move the pointer by 4000 bytes and tries to write there. This is not allowed, as you don't own the memory where the pointer now points (or in fact there are even more strict rules). Therefore any operation with that memory can have different unexpected results, including a crash.

Note that I say "can have", not "must have". This is what is called [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): the write can succeed, can work, but write a different value, can crash your program now or later, can format your drive, etc. It can even be that read success, but write does not. No specific result is guaranteed by the language.

In fact, in most implementations and in typical cases as long as you do not go far away, it will seem to work (although might overwrite other important data), but when you go further, it will crash your program.

Comment: I could write to a memory +64 or -4000 relative to my pointer but then if I wanted to go further I could just read from those memories. And I read 0. Can you tell me the rules if there are? I know that you are allowed to write anywhere in memory as long as the thread is running.

Comment: well this is a pretty nice explanation. Thanks a lot sir. That means windows is almost hackproof in that direction. So a program can't screw up the memory as it pleases. There are some control structures which limit the program. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj, exactly. On modern mainstream OSes programs are not allowed to access other programs' memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. You saved me a lot of effort and of course enlightened me. Thanks a lot! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj, also just came to my mind: even the zero that you were reading from there does not of course mean that the memory at that location is zero. That's what undefined behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

`point` is an `int*`, so after this line

```
point+=4000;
```

You are now pointing `4000` `int` addresses past `value2`. You cannot try to write to that address since you did not allocate it.

Comment: I would say, he can try to write to that address (as long as he can live with the consequences ;)

Comment: Is such thing even possible? Do I have to allocate it in order to write to it?
Isn't the registry open to any change from the processor? I can actually read from it and I see 0.

@tobi303 yes I wanted the write to that address but the progrm crashes if I do so. ;(

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj well, thats one of the possible consequences I was refering to. You can do it, but that doesnt mean that you should do it ;)

Comment: @tobi303 I realized I CAN'T do it on the mainstream OSes like Windows(at least that where I tried to do it). They have some control structures which forbid the program to write to an address or even read from it which just happened to me for 0x8 address on my PC.
I wanted to do it to have fun hacking some PC, but wise people have thought it well :((( it can't be helped :P

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj sorry I cant really follow you. What you did leads to plain undefined behavior (maybe I should have said it before and I am quite sure that this is what CoryKramer meant when saying "You cannot.."). Making any assumptions based on trying to run your code is rather meaningless when there is undefined behavior

Comment: @tobi303 ye thats right. An unpredictable program is worthless and I understood more from the question so thanks a lot to you and everyone who helped me understand.

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj Good to hear we could help you, but I have one last comment: undefined behavior is not the same as unpredictable. Actually most programs execution is not fully predictable and that is just fine (think of user interaction or rounding errors in floating point arithmetic)

Answer (score 1):

```
*point = 0;  //the buggy line
```

No, this is not the buggy line.

```
point+=4000;
```

This is the buggy line. This statement advances the pointer value by 4000*sizeof(int).

That's clearly not what you wanted.

You forgot an asterisk, here.

Comment: In fact that's exactly what I wanted. Since size of integers is 4 byte then I wanted to advance 1000 integer addresses forward to change that address to what I want. I could go without modifying it and it printed out a 0. When I tried to modify it I couldnt. The program would crash

Comment: Well, actually you're advancing 4000 integer addresses. Adding an integer to a pointer address advances the pointer by n*sizeof(*ptr). However, since there is no 1000, or 4000 integer array anywhere around here, you will end up pointing to some random memory location, and attempting to dereference it will obviously produce a crash, or lead to undefined behavior. As you've observed. In order to advance a pointer by n, you know, you really have to have n actual objects after what the pointer is pointing to. And you have none.

Comment: Oh ye ye I see... I got it!!! I am currently studying about them, the dynamic arrays, new and delete. So it makes sense to me that this behavior was undefined and  random to the address I pointed to. Thanks for the answer! :)